# Is it possible to save and access and search an array or list containing elements with different length in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, array-difference, variable-length

Is it possible to save and access array or list containing elements with different length? For instance, I want to save `data=[s,r,a,se]` r,a are scalar but `s` and `se` are an arrays with 4 elements.(in python language)

For instance in one time:`(s,r,a,se)` are different in different times

```
 s=[1,3,4,6] r=5 a=7 se=[11,12,13,14] 
 data=[s,r,a,se]=[[1,3,4,6],5,7,[11,12,13,14]]
```

How I can define the array containing them to be able to call them similar to the following code:

```
s=[data[0] for data in minibatch]
r=[data[1] for data in minibatch]
a=[data[2] for data in minibatch]
se=[data[3] for data in minibatch]
```

Also, how I can extract (**Find**) that is there a special`[stest,rtest,atest,setest]` in `data` (`stest,setest` are with 4 elements)

**For instance:** I want to see can I find `[[1,2,3,4],5,6,[7,8,9,10]]`  in data which is something similar to:                                                  `[ [[1,2,3,4],5,6,[7,8,9,10]] ,[[...,...,...,...],...,...,  [...,...,...,...]], [[18,20,31,42],53,666,[27,48,91,120]]]`

If I did not find I append to it otherwise nothing is happened!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them in a new list:

```
 new_list = [s, r, a, se]
```

But you'll have to be careful managing this list

Answer (score 0):

```
# This is a great opportunity to explore dictionaries

# lets take the examples you have given in variales
s=[1,3,4,6] 
r=5 
a=7 
se=[11,12,13,14]

# make a dictionary out of them, with keys which are 
# the same as the variable name
my_dict = {'s':s,
           'r':r,
           'a':a,
           'se':se}

# lets see what that looks like
print(my_dict)
print()

# to retrieve 2nd (=ix=1) element of s
# the format to do this is simple
# ditionary_variable_name['the string which is the key'][index_of_the_list]
s2 = my_dict['s'][1]
print(s2)
print()

# to retrieve all of se
se_retrieved = my_dict['se']
print(se_retrieved)

# you can further experiment with this
```

output of sample:

```
{'s': [1, 3, 4, 6], 'r': 5, 'a': 7, 'se': [11, 12, 13, 14]}

3

[11, 12, 13, 14]
```

In order to write to this, you need to do something like this:

```
my_dict['se'] = [15, 16, 17, 18]
```

or

```
my_dict['se'][2] = 19
```

Comment: Thanks but all of them are variable(s,a,r,se) that changing during the several iterations! How we can write them?

Comment: Thanks Edwin, but  I think you did not understand my question correctly, my question is that how I can find that for instance: [[1,2,3,4],5,6,[7,8,9,10]] is existed in data which is something similar to:                                 [ [[1,2,3,4],5,6,[7,8,9,10]] ,[[...,...,...,...],...,...,  [...,...,...,...]], [[18,20,31,42],53,666,[27,48,91,120]]]